# Prove or disprove that the function is convex on a certain interval

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, convexity-inequality

Let $-\ln(2)\leq x<0$ and $n\geq 1$ a natural number then define :

$$f(x)=\left(0.5+\sum_{k=1}^{2n}e^{k^2x}\right)\left(0.5+\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^ke^{k^2x}\right)$$

Then it seems we have the following claim :

$$f''(x)>0$$

Proof for the case $n=1$ :

this case is very simple if we differentiate one time and substitute $y=e^x$ we get a fourth degree  polynomial in subsituting again and to show that the derivative increase we differentatiate the polynomial to get a third degree polynomial .The rest is smooth using Cardano'formula.

Question :

How to (dis)prove the claim ?

Thanks !

Comment: The factors can be rewritten as $a-b$ and $a+b$, so the entire expression is $a^2-b^2$ where $a$ is $e$ to the even square $x$ and $b$ is $e$ to the odd square $x$'s.  Don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor good observation ! I think that something interesting can be done here . Thanks !